# ¿Que puede causar este error syntax error, unexpected '$nombre' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'?

Tags: php, clase

```
class Productos{

    var $nombre;

    public function mostrarNombre(){
        echo '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#"><?= '$nombre' ?></a </h3>';
    }
}
```

Me dice que el error en mi código es:

> **syntax error, unexpected '$nombre' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'**

Pero no entiendo por qué?.

Comment: te falta concatenar dicha variable

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Se trata de un error tipográfico, olvidaste el operador de concatenación de cadenas `.` para agregar el contenido de la variable a las cadenas que rodean a dicha variable.

Answer (score 6):

El error se debe a que no estas [concatenando correctamente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) la variable `$nombre`.

#### Solución:

Debe utilizar el punto (`.`) para concatenar.

```
echo '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">' . $nombre . '</a></h3>';
```

---

### Clases y objetos:

Una vez que soluciones el problema de concatenación, te encontraras con otro problema, y es que no estas haciendo referencia correctamente a la propiedad `$nombre` de la clase `Producto`.

Además (*como señala @Aprendiz*) no es correcto usar `var $nombre` para definir una propiedad.

#### Solución:

- Las propiedades de clases deben ser definidas como ['public', 'private' o 'protected'](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php).
- Para acceder a las propiedades de la clase, debes utilizar [`$this`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
class Productos{

    public $nombre = 'Nombre';

    public function mostrarNombre(){
        echo '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">' . $this->nombre . '</a></h3>';
   }
}
```

Comment: En lugar de duplicar contenido con aporte que sería similar al tuyo mejor te apoyo y te doy +1, sin embargo no sería más conveniente indicarle no usar var y mejor el modificador de acceso?

Comment: Genial de hecho ya cuentas con mi voto 

Comment: Además de mi +1 pongo mi granito de arena. La explicación del error es que el analizador ha encontrado una variable (`T_VARIABLE`) cuando se esperaba el fin de la instrucción (o un operador).

Answer (score 1):

Para concatenar cadenas en PHP se utiliza el '.'

Ejemplo

```
$nombre = 'Lucas';
$apellido = 'Gonzalez';
$nombreCompleto = "<label>".$nombre.$apellido."</label>";
echo $nombreCompleto;
```

Answer (score 1):

tu error esta en la concatenación, debes usar los puntos entre las variables y el mensaje, yo lo haría distinto , mira esta solución invirtiendo las comillas simples y dobles:

```
class Productos{

    public $nombre = 'Nombre';

    public function mostrarNombre(){
        $nombre = $this->nombre;
        echo "<h3 class='product-name'><a href='#'>$nombre</a></h3>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**La respuesta:**

1) Las variable que se encuentra fuera de un metodo en la clase se llama usando `$this->variable`

2) No necesita llamar nuevamente al php y hacer un `echo <?= '$nombre' ?>` ya estas dentro de un echo. solo concatenas la variable.

Tu codigo quedaria con las correciones de esta forma:

```
<?php

    // Creando la clase
    class Productos {

       public $nombre;  // se pone public para acceder fuera de la clase

            public function mostrarNombre() {
                echo '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">'.  $this->nombre .'</a </h3>';
                // las variable fuera de los metodo en la clase de llaman $tihs->variable
            }
    }

    // Creando la instancia para clase
    $nuevoProducto = new Productos;
    // asignando variable de clase
    $nuevoProducto->nombre = 'Saludos Desde PHP';
    //  ejecutar metodo de clase
    $nuevoProducto->mostrarNombre();

?>
```

La salida en pantalla del codigo seria la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba este codigo completamente operativo!!!